# Is it necessary to duplicate data when using many web API services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, soa

I am creating an architecture based on multiple web API services and I am looking for the best way to structure the data. Data is being duplicated in the current structure.

I have an applications database and web API project which stores and manages all of the applications that are being created within the companuy. This contains a name and a GUID.

This information is retrieved and managed using the web API service.

I have another API service and database that manages vehicle types. The issue I am having is that certain vehicle types can only be used by certain applications. Because of this, 
the vehicle types system needs to be aware of the applications that exist in the applications database. Eg a client could make a get request to see all vehicle types a certain application has access to.

So in this database I would have three tables, vehicle types,applications,vehicle types application links.
I need a complete duplication of the application database within the vehicle type database in order to manage this mapping.

This duplication doesn't feel quite right. Data would have to be managed in multiple places and kept in sync.
This isn't an isolated case either. As the infrastructure of the company grows there is going to be a large dependency on the products table by a number of other services.
I am reluctant to make duplicates all over the place.

Do you have any thoughts on the best way to manage data in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not embed application knowledge in the vehicle service.  That won't scale.

I'd also wonder why managing vehicle types is not the province of a single vehicle service.

If this is a REST service I'd partition the vehicles database into different resources/folders/URLs so applications can ask for what they're entitled to.  The URL for an HTTP GET query might be `https://host/vehicle/type/{type}`

If you want to enforce what an application is entitled to, perhaps another thing to think about is role-based security.  Provide URLs that give access to those resources and credentials only to those who are allowed to use them.

It sounds like the vehicle service is reference data that applications use in transactions.  Applications can request instances of vehicles, but it's not "duplication".  The vehicle service is still the source of truth.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look into this.